# Accessing variables outside of for loop in Golang

Tags: csv, for-loop, go, scope, func

I'm trying to read a CSV file to store the values in a variable. However, I couldn't access the variables outside of the for loop

```
func GetKeys(filename string) {
    var record []string
    var err error
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    // Create a new reader.
    reader := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(file))
    for {
        record, err = reader.Read()
        // Stop at EOF.
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v", record) // works fine
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", record[0]) // works fine too
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", record) // returns empty slice
}

func main() {
    GetKeys("credentials.csv")
}
```

Comment: Put the `break` at the end (after your `Print`s inside the loop) and you'll find that `record` is empty on the last iteration where you get `EOF`, therefore it's still empty after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop breaks when `reader.Read()` returns `io.EOF`. This happens when your input is consumed.

At the same time (when `io.EOF` is returned), the returned record will be `nil`. [`Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader.Read):

> If there is no data left to be read, **Read returns nil, io.EOF**.

So you assign `nil` to the `record` variable, the loop breaks, and you inspect the `record` variable.

If your intent is to hold the last record, store it in a separate variable, and do not "overwrite" it with the last `nil` record:

```
var lastRecord []string
for {
    record, err = reader.Read()
    // Stop at EOF.
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    lastRecord = record
    fmt.Printf("%v", record) // works fine
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", record[0]) // works fine too
}
fmt.Printf("%v\n", lastRecord) // this will be the last non-nil record
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation